# Is it possible to earn Steam Achievements while using Steam In-Home Streaming/Link?

Tags: steam, achievements, steam-in-home-streaming

Can you earn Achievements when playing using Steam In-Home Streaming/Link?

While playing remotely achievements aren’t unlocking. If I play normally on the PC they do.

Comment: Do you maybe play with a friend and you don't own the game yourself? I often used to have trouble gathering achievements when I used a friend's library and did not own the game or vice versa. However your question seems to involve only one steam account and thus this is probably not the case.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 exactly, we’re talking about one single account. No other accounts or players involved.